# Using lambda() in r for coefficients of matrix

Tags: r, matrix, lambda

I am really stumped with some code that I am using from a colleague.

I have the following model, where factor 1 has ABC options and factor 2 has ab options

```
model<-aov(response~factor1*factor2,data=mydata)
coef(model)

(Intercept)                factor1-A                     factor1-B 
  1.82404                        -0.29790                  -0.80398 
 factor2-b                factor1-A:factor2-b     factor1-B:factor2-b 
 -0.37816                        0.04560                   0.07672
```

I then want to determine the main effects and pairwise comparisons within this model.  So my colleague gave me this code:

```
lambda <- rbind(c(0, 1, 0, 0,1/2, 0),   #Main effect: factor1, A-C
                c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0,1/2),   #Main effect: factor1, B-C
                c(0, 0, 0, 1,1/3, 1/3), #Main effect factor2: a-b
esticon(model,lambda)
```

I can't figure out how to manipulate the lambda codes so that I can get the main effect for "factor1, A-B"  Does anyone know how to do this?  I've looked around online, and what I find doesn't have a good explanation for how to use these matrices.  If someone could point me toward a good reference for how these lambda matrices work, that would be great too.  Also, I have installed the libary (doBy).  That's where esticon came from.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Don't have access to your data but it sounds like you're looking to do a factorial ANOVA.

First you'll need to run a `TukeyHSD(model, ...)`and then you can get more information on factors 1 and 2 by using `$factor1` and `$factor2`. If you want to take a look at the interaction between the two for all of the various levels you can use

```
$`factor1:factor2`
```

[Here is a link](http://ww2.coastal.edu/kingw/statistics/R-tutorials/factorial.html) to some more information that you may find helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I can see that the information for those codes is present if I run a TukeyHSD test.  However, I'm running a two-way (or factorial ANOVA) and then I'm trying to use this code to get the sidak adjusted p-values (instead of using the TukeyHSD method).

Comment: not really but I think my coworker solved the problem.

Comment: @Jini, can I ask what the solution was? Still a bit confused as to what was actually needed and it'd be a good learning exercise for me to better understand the issue at hand. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, I added a line to that lambda code:  c(0,-1, 1, 0,-1/2,1/2) #Main effect: Factor A to Factor B